# descriptor 'get' requires a 'dict' object but received a 'generator'

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code.I am getting error in this code line.

```
     inverse_vocabulary = dict.get((word, i) for i, word in enumerate(vocabulary))
```

My error is:

```
  TypeError  Traceback (most recent call last)
  >     <ipython-input-27-7941d5453736> in <module>()
  >      21 
  >      22     vocabulary = open(r"G:\final year 
  >     project\data/vocabulary.txt").read().split("\n")
  >     ---> 23     inverse_vocabulary = dict.get((word, i) for i, word in 
  >     enumerate(vocabulary))
  >      24 
  >      25 TypeError: descriptor 'get' requires a 'dict' object but 
  received a 
  >     'generator'
```

Comment: And what did you expect `dict.get((word, i) for i, word in 
enumerate(vocabulary))` to do? That line makes no sense (which is what python is telling you as well).

Comment: You probably just want `dict` instead of `dict.get` at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, dumb detail, but Python is not a compiled language - it is an interpreted language - just for your own future reference

Second, as the commentor said - you're passing a generator into dict.get(). Wrap that generator in a dict() call to evaluate it to a dictionary.

```
inverse_vocabulary = dict.get(dict((word, i) for i, word in enumerate(vocabulary)))
```